# Drag and drop images individually

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5

I am looking for a way to drag images one at a time around in iOS(instead a bunch at once). I already asked a question like this and did get some answers , but it didn't work. I believe it didn't work because my situation may be different then expected and that is why I am posting the same question. I heard gestures may work, but I tried so many different types of code I didn't get any results. Please help.

Kindest regards.

```
cowKeys = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"cow",@"cow1",@"cow2",@"cow3",nil];

-(void) dealcows {

    while (current cow <= 11) {

        currentName = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png", [cowsShuffled        objectAtIndex:currentCard] ];
        totalcowrValue = totalDealerValue + [[dictionary valueForKey:[cowsShuffled objectAtIndex:currentcow]] intValue];

        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];

        if (currentcow== 1){

            if (autoPlay == YES){
                imageView.image= [UIImage imageNamed:currentName];
            } else {
                imageView.image= [UIImage imageNamed:currentName];
            }


            cow = (UIImageView *)[self.view viewWithTag:11];
            cow.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
            cow1 = (UIImageView *)[self.view viewWithTag:1];
            cow1.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        }
    }
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)set withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    CGPoint a = [[set anyObject] locationInView:self.view];
    CGPoint r = [[set anyObject] locationInView:self.view];
    cow.center = a;

    cow1.center = r;

}
```

Comment: Do you want to drag and drop images into Xcode ?

Comment: No, I want to touch an image and drag it around.  Thus the void touches moved method.

Comment: Why did you set two imageViews' center in the method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `UIPanGestureRecognizer` to the imageView you want to move and add @selector to that `UIPanGestureRecognizer`.
Believe me i have done this moving thing with CALayers and subviews. It works like butter..